# Getting Undefined while accessing the values of data object inside map in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dictionary, next.js

// while accessing the object values from data, I'm getting undefined in map

// ../data/section1

```
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    image: './images/homepage/xbox-games.png',
    text: 'Buy Xbox games and consoles',
}, {
    id: 2,
    image: './images/homepage/shop_surface_devices.webp',
    text: 'Shop surface devices',
}, {
    id: 3,
    image: './images/homepage/choose_your_ms_365.png',
    text: 'Choose your Microsoft 365',
}, {
    id: 4,
    image: './images/homepage/shop_windows_10.png',
    text: 'Shop Windows 10',
}]
export default data;
```

// the actual component

```
    import data from "../data/section1";
    
    const Section1 = () => {
    
      return (
        <>
            <div class="mx-20">
                {data.map((vals) => {
                  <div class="">
                    <img src={vals.image}/>
                    <p>{vals.text}</p>
                  </div>
                })}
            </div>
        </>
      )
    }
    
    export default Section1;
```

Comment: How does the data looks like?

Comment: const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      image: './images/homepage/xbox-games.png',
      text: 'Buy Xbox games and consoles',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      image: './images/homepage/shop_surface_devices.webp',
      text: 'Shop surface devices',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      image: './images/homepage/choose_your_ms_365.png',
      text: 'Choose your Microsoft 365',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      image: './images/homepage/shop_windows_10.png',
      text: 'Shop Windows 10',
    }  ]
  
  export default data;

Comment: Did you try  `console.log(data)`?

Comment: yes it is showing correctly, only while accessing in map I'm getting undefined

Comment: you forgot to return JSX from your map. `return <div>...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
return JSX from the map

    import data from "../data/section1";
    
    const Section1 = () => {
    
    
      return (
        <>
            <div class="mx-20">
                {data.map((vals) => {
                  return (
                    <div class="">
                      <img src={vals.image}/>
                      <p>{vals.text}</p>
                    </div> 
                  )
                })}
            </div>
        </>
      )
    }
    
    export default Section1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, then tried the first bracket instead of the second, and it resolved the problem

import data from "../data/section1";

```
const Section1 = () => {

  return (
    <>
        <div class="mx-20">
            {data.map((vals) => (
              <div class="">
                <img src={vals.image}/>
                <p>{vals.text}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Section1;
```